# Trouble with importing UnityNEAT into a preexisting unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some trouble with importing https://github.com/lordjesus/UnityNEAT into a unity project that I have already made (https://github.com/ryanboldi/EvolutionaryStructures).

In the README, the author says to "to use NEAT in your Unity project, simply download the UnityNEAT folder and import it to your Unity project. In the folder you will find a few example experiments that you can copy and use for inspiration."

I first tried dragging the UnityNEAT project file into the top directory of my unity project (The one including Assets and Logs etc.) and realized that i was not able to access any of the scripts and classes that are part of the package.

I have attempted to drag the whole UnityNEAT Project file into my Assets folder, to which I received many "Assembly with name 'Unity.CollabProxy.Editor' already exists (Assets/UnityNEAT/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16/Editor/Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.asmdef)" errors.

I also attempted to drag the Assets folder of the UnityNEAT Project file into my own project's Assets folder, to which I received a missing namespace error.

I apologize for the beginner question, but how do I *actually* import this package into my Unity Project?

Thank you!

Comment: It is a reference so in VS in Solution Explorer add the reference by browsing to the bin folder of project and select executable (or dll).  Then you would need to add using statements are top of the c# module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around the web at implementations of UnityNEAT, I solved this issue by only dragging "CarExperiment", "Resources", and "SharpNEAT" from the Assets folder of UnityNEAT. This resulted in fixed the conflicting files, as well as only de-cluttering my project Assets folder.

To install/use them, @jdweng's comment will come in handy.